# Java Swing- Panel not appearing in frame

Tags: java, swing

I am new to swing and am wondering why my login panel isn't appearing in the frame. I believe it should show on the left side of the frame, is this correct? What needs to be changed to make the panel appear. Thanks.

Here is the GUIFrame code

```
public class GUIFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GUIFrame(){
    Container container = getContentPane();
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenDimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    setSize(screenDimension.width/2, screenDimension.height/2);
    setLocation(screenDimension.width/4,screenDimension.height/4);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    add(new Login(this));

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Here is the panels code:

```
public class Login extends JPanel {

private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
private JLabel username_label = new JLabel("Username :");
private JLabel password_label = new JLabel("Password :");
private JTextField username_text = new JTextField();
private JPasswordField password_text = new JPasswordField();
private GUIFrame frame;

public Login(GUIFrame frame){
    this.frame = frame;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,20,40));
    addComponents();
}

public void addComponents(){
    panel.add(username_label);
    panel.add(username_text);
    panel.add(password_label);
    panel.add(password_text);
    panel.add(cancel);
    panel.add(submit);
}
```

}

Here is the main method which displays the frame:

```
public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Project project = new Project();
}

public Project() {
    //Login login = new Login();
    GUIFrame frame = new GUIFrame();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. What does `Login`'s frame field get used for? What does `addComponents` do? Please give a runnable example

Comment: @Michael Sorry, have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
panel.add(username_label);
panel.add(username_text);
panel.add(password_label);
panel.add(password_text);
panel.add(cancel);
panel.add(submit);
```

You create a separate JPanel and add the component to this panel, but you never add the panel to your Login panel.

Your Login panel already is a JPanel, so there is no need to create another JPanel.

The code should just be:

```
add(username_label);
add(username_text);
add(password_label);
add(password_text);
add(cancel);
add(submit);
```

There is also no reason to pass the JFrame as a parameter to your Login class.

Also, you are using the invokeLater() incorrectly. All Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). So you should also include the new GuiFrame() inside the invokeLater().

Generally there is no need to have a separate JFrame class. The logic in your Project class should simply create an instance of the frame and add the Login panel to the frame. In other words don't extend JFrame.